# Phone number formatting validation

Tags: javascript, jquery

How would I validate with Javascript/jQuery that a phone number matches the format of +322123456?

1. The +32 is mandatory, and the phone number begins with it.
2. After the +32, 8 or 9 numbers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try

```
\+32\d{8,9}
```

**[DEMO](http://rubular.com/r/Wlb6DMJ6GD)**

Comment: The OP said the "+32" is mandatory.. so it should be `\+32\d{8,9}` ;)

Comment: I tried this : http://jsfiddle.net/Kris_I/srvpQ/2/ but not work, I missed something probably

Answer (score 5):

Use regex to do that.

```
/\+32\d{8,9}/
```

Answer (score 0):

You use this regex : `\+32[0-9]{8}[0-9]+` to check that.

Comment: This doesn't quite work. Using your same format you can have 10 or more characters after "+32". This `\+32[0-9]{8,9}` will work.

Comment: LOL I LOVE RegEx questions! They always get 10 "answers" from people who claim their solution works, and they never do. Why don't people TEST things before they post?